# How to implements Spring Data Elasticsearch 8.4 and repositories?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm creating new Java POC in order to test Eelasticsearch 8.4 features.

To do this, i found a configuration file on internet :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.poc.elastic")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.poc"})
public class ElasticConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

I also create a repository class :

```java
public interface ItemRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Item, String> {}
```

Now, i just want to create a quality code and no longer use `RestHighLevelClient` because it is deprecated.

I have read there is a new implementation but i don't know how to create `ElasticsearchOperations`from new `ElasticsearchClient` (@EnableElasticsearchRepositories uses elasticsearchTemplate by default).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.poc.elastic")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.poc"})
public class ElasticConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost:9200", 9200)).build();
        return restClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTransport getElasticsearchTransport() {
        return new RestClientTransport(
                getRestClient(), new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    }


    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(getElasticsearchTransport());
        return client;
    }
}
```

I'm using spring 2.7.3.

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

The new Elasticsearch client is available as an optional way to connect to Elasticsearch in version 4.4, that is what Spring Boot 2.7.3 uses. Check [the Spring Data Elasticsearch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.3-4.4.new-clients) for how to integrate this new client.